# In Hotelling's theory, why create a statistic and calculate the likelihood instead of using the maximum likelihood estimated normal distribution?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, anomaly-detection, hotelling-t2

In Hotelling's theory, when data is assumed to be generated from a normal distribution, a statistic based on the Mahalanobis distance is calculated, and the degree of anomaly of the data is calculated from the distribution that follows it.

However, during the calculation process, the mean and variance of the normal distribution are estimated by maximum likelihood.

Since the probability of data generation can be calculated from the maximum likelihood estimated normal distribution, I feel that the degree of anomaly can also be calculated, but the Hotelling theory does not do so.
Is the reason for this because calculating the anomaly from the distribution followed by the statistic based on the Mahalanobis distance is more accurate?